# Apply easing animation effect to JavaScript sliding form

Tags: javascript, css

I have built out a form that slides in/out from the right side of the screen using JavaScript I found from a tutorial. Everything works but the person who reviewed it felt that the animation looks too "robotic" (or linear). It was suggested that I try to add a CSS3-like easing effect for the slide in and slide out JavaScript animations. I'd like to do this but, at the same time, I don't want to a) Redo all the code I have set in place since it does work so I don't want to scrap it all and start over, and b) Make the existing functions far too complicated or confusing to maintain just to create an easing effect.

Here is the JavaScript I have right now:

```
var slidingDiv = document.getElementById("slider");

/*
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 Function to activate form button to open the slider.
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 */

function open_panel() {
    slideIt();
    var a = document.getElementById("sidebar");
    a.setAttribute("id", "sidebar1");
    a.setAttribute("onclick", "close_panel()");
}
/*
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 Function to slide the sidebar form (open form)
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function slideIt() {
    var stopPosition = -20;
    if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.right) < stopPosition) {
        slidingDiv.style.right = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.right) + 3 + "px";
        setTimeout(slideIt, 0);
    }
}
/*
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 Function to activate form button to close the slider.
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function close_panel() {
    slideIn();
    a = document.getElementById("sidebar1");
    a.setAttribute("id", "sidebar");
    a.setAttribute("onclick", "open_panel()");
}
/*
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 Function to slide the sidebar form (slide in form)
 ------------------------------------------------------------
 */
function slideIn() {
    var slidingDiv = document.getElementById("slider");
    var stopPosition = -320;
    if (parseInt(slidingDiv.style.right) > stopPosition) {
        slidingDiv.style.right = parseInt(slidingDiv.style.right) - 2 + "px";
        setTimeout(slideIn, 1);
    }

}
```

Here is the form HTML

```
<div id="slider" style="right: -320px;" class="register-photo">
    <div class="form-inner">
        <div class="form-container">
            <form method="post" action="#" id="browserHangForm">
                <a id="sidebar" onclick="open_panel()">
                    <span id="arrow" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left icon-arrow"></span>
                </a>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="*First Name" autofocus="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="last_name" placeholder="*Last Name" autofocus="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Email" placeholder="*Email" autofocus="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Company" placeholder="*Company" autofocus="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block button-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <a href="privacy-policy" class="already" target="_blank"><span
                        class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock icon-lock"></span>We will never share your information.</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the most relevant CSS:

```
html{
    max-width: 100% !important;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: static;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.register-photo {
    margin-top: 101px;
    z-index: 99;
    position: fixed;
}

.register-photo .form-container{
    z-index: 9;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;
}

a:active{
    background-color: transparent;
}

.button-submit{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just rip out the clunky JavaScript code and replaced it with jQuery, which seems much cleaner and easier to maintain. Got right of a lot of things that bugged me (reduced the use of css IDs and made them classes, stripped out the inline function calls, and changed the sliding effect to be controlled by one function instead of 4

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//This function checks if we are in mobile view or not to determine the
//UI behavior of the form.
    window.onload = checkWindowSize();

    var arrowicon = $(".arrow");
    var overlay = $("#overlay");
    var slidingDiv = $(".slider");
    var closeBtn = $(".closeBtn");
    var mobileBtn = $(".mobile-btn");

//When the page loads, check the screen size.
//If the screen size is less than 768px, you want to get the function
//that opens the form as a popup in the center of the screen
//Otherwise, you want it to be a slide-out animation from the right side
    function checkWindowSize() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
            //get function to open form at center of screen
            setTimeout(formModal, 5000);
            function formModal() {
                slidingDiv.addClass("showForm")
                overlay.addClass("showOverlay");
                overlay.removeClass('hideOverlay');
                mobileBtn.addClass("hideBtn");
            }
        }
        else {
            //when we aren't in mobile view, let's just have the form slide out from the right
            setTimeout(slideOut, 5000);
            function slideOut() {
                slidingDiv.animate({'right': '-20px'}).addClass('open');
                arrowicon.addClass("glyphicon-arrow-right");
                arrowicon.removeClass("glyphicon-arrow-left");
                overlay.addClass("showOverlay");
                overlay.removeClass("hideOverlay");
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     ------------------------------------------------------------
     Functions to open/close form like a modal in center of screen in mobile view
     ------------------------------------------------------------
     */

    mobileBtn.click(function () {
        slidingDiv.addClass("showForm");
        slidingDiv.removeClass("hideForm");
        overlay.addClass("showOverlay");
        overlay.removeClass('hideOverlay');
        mobileBtn.addClass("hideBtn");
    });
    closeBtn.click(function () {
        slidingDiv.addClass("hideForm");
        slidingDiv.removeClass("showForm");
        overlay.removeClass("showOverlay");
        overlay.addClass("hideOverlay")
        mobileBtn.removeClass("hideBtn");
    });


    /*
     ------------------------------------------------------------
     Function to slide the sidebar form out/in
     ------------------------------------------------------------
     */
    arrowicon.click(function () {
        if (slidingDiv.hasClass('open')) {
            slidingDiv.animate({'right': '-390px'}).removeClass('open');
            arrowicon.addClass("glyphicon-arrow-left");
            arrowicon.removeClass("glyphicon-arrow-right");
            overlay.removeClass("showOverlay");
            overlay.addClass("hideOverlay");

        } else {
            slidingDiv.animate({'right': '-20px'}).addClass('open');
            arrowicon.addClass("glyphicon-arrow-right");
            arrowicon.removeClass("glyphicon-arrow-left");
            overlay.addClass("showOverlay");
            overlay.removeClass("hideOverlay");
        }

    });

});
```